# Android onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)

Tags: android

In my application during normal operation the onRestoreInstanceStatance function is executed and causes a null pointer exception in some listener, without invoking that listener. My app contains a lot of data that I write to a file in onPause and restore in onResume and onRestoreInstanceStatance. How can I make the app stable?

Comment: You probably should reconsider writing so much state data in onresume and onpause. Especially to files. What is it that you're trying to do? Why do you need to do so much there?

Comment: i have lot's of temp data .My problem is , i have lost these data after a long time put the app in background and take other application ,when resumes the application i have lost the data, for avoiding it i write the data every time in to file when am exist from the application ,but now the problem is getting null pointer exception. During resumes sometimes my onResotre will call and getting null pointer exception in some listeners that am not interacting.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you assign listeners in the end of the `onResume`, that will ensure no listeners are fired BEFORE the initial state is set. Then in `onPause` first thing to do is to remove listeners.